# Open cone homeomorphic to the Euclidean space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Let $X$ be a topological space and the open cone $C(X)$ over $X$ is defined to be $X \times [0,1)$ with $X \times \{0\}$ identified. Suppose $C(X)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^4$, can we prove that $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^3$.

Comment: No, you will never get theorems like this except maybe in very very small dimensions like 0 or 1. General spaces are too wild. An explicit counterexample to your question should be given by $S^3/W$ where $W$ is the Whitehead continuum: equivalently the one-point compactificiation of the Whitehead manifold. If you suppose X is a compact manifold then the answer is yes and follows from Poincare.

Comment: @mme do you have a reference? Does it follow from the results in this paper? https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1965-71-04/S0002-9904-1965-11394-5/

Comment: @IanAgol That $(S^3/W) \times \Bbb R$ is homeomorphic to $S^3 \times \Bbb R$ is Theorem 4.16 of [Ferry's notes](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sferry/ps/geotop.pdf) though of course this isn't the original reference. Then OP's space is obtained by adding one end in the end compactificiation (instead of both ends, which would give the suspension itself).